# Securing APIs using IAM

Tags: api, security, oauth, identity, saml

I have developed Web APIs which need to be secured. This means only authenticated applications are able to consume these APIs.

These APIs are used in the background so the application itself needs to be authenticated not the user that runs the application. The user will not notice anything.

Which technology is the best to make these APIs secure?

- OpenID
- OAuth
- SAML
- (something else)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the calls to be made within the context of a given user and just want to ensure that only known applications can call into your API's then issuing each application an [API key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface_key) is a much simpler way of accomplishing this without having to worry about compliance with the protocols you listed.

On the other hand, if your applications needs to call the API's on behalf of a given user, protocols like OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 start to make more sense. However, in order for people to be able to give an accurate recommendation you may want to try to give more concrete details about your use case.

Comment: Thank you. Using API Key only will not meet customer's requirement. The application must be authenticated so we need to implement OAuth 2.0 using Client_ID and Client_Secret.

Comment: No worries, like I said if you need user context OAuth 2.0 is probably your best bet for API authorization. It's not linear to implement though.